# Link doesn't open up on first click

Tags: css, onclick, click

I tried to look into this but nothing I do seems to work out.

When I use Chrome, I can click on the link located right below each image in the gallery without any issues .

When I use Safari though, I have to click several times and only a specific area of the link will fire the window.

Here is a screenshot of the link I try to trigger on Safari:

[image]

The problem arises when clicking on any of the items listed in the image gallery.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre] (this means, your _code must be in the question itself_), along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work. Try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser.

Comment: Ok thank you, but I don't have the knowledge to see or reproduce the error in a technical way.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a look over the site you share a link for using the timeline and resource debuging on Chrome and Safari.

It would appear that the issue with the link is not that it doesn't work on first click. It is that the DOM has not fully loaded. If you wait till the DOM has finished its first pass at the HTML, approx 4 full seconds on my connection(~72Mb), the link will work on first click even before all assets (images and JS) has finished loading.

On Chrome this particular page seems to manage to loading the HTML in under 1.9 seconds, before starting to load in assets. Which is why it feels like the link works first time.

Here is a Google analysis of yuour page that reports the same finding. Note Time to Interactive is ***14 seconds***

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcfcj-immo.com%2Facheter%2F

Comment: Actually 4 seconds may have been partially cached. When opening in a private safari browser it took a full 11 seconds before the first parse was complete.

Comment: Thank you for that! But I checked again, and if I stay on the part of the link that doesn't work and click multiple times (beyond 4 seconds), it still won't open. Do you have any idea of how this could be fixed?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcfcj-immo.com%2Facheter%2F

Comment: When I click on the link from left to right and vice versa, it opens up. It's strange.

Comment: I checked again and it seems to be the clickable area that is not aligned with the text.